# How to get GCP Bearer/Access token programmatically in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, command-line-interface, gcloud, access-token

I am using Google Cloud's Vertex API for making a AI app. I am currently working on the feature of getting caption/description for an image using this [API](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/generative-ai/image/image-captioning#performance-limits). I am using the following function to do the same:

```
const fetchCaptionForImage = async (image) => {
    const accessToken = "..."
    const uri = "..."
    const body = {...}

    try {
        const response = await axios.post(uri, body, {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
            }
        })
        console.log(response.data.predictions);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
}
```

From the documentation, I can only see that to generate `accessToken` you have to use gcloud cli command: `gcloud auth print-access-token`. I am able to get the result using the command line's accessToken.

But since the accessToken expires, I want to generate the access-token programmatically. I saw some posts where this is explained but they are mostly outdated or in python.

I want to get `access-token`  programmatically in `Node.js`. How to do that? Thank you.

Comment: Where your code is running? What's your code calling (Cloud Functions or VertexAI directly)? How do you manage the control access to the backend? (IAM, custom rule)

Comment: My code is running on GCP. Not sure what are Cloud Functions but it is calling the following URI (https://us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1/projects/project-name/locations/us-central1/publishers/google/models/imagetext:predict). For control access, I have a service account.

Answer (score 0):

According to the URL in the comment, you are using VertexAI serving service. In your code you can get an access token like that in NodeJS

```
    const {GoogleAuth} = require('google-auth-library');
...
...

    const auth = new GoogleAuth({
        scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'
    });
    const token = await auth.getAccessToken();
    console.log(token);
```